# Method that returns whether a specified word can be made with specified letter counts

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, boolean, logic

A previous method called letterCounts required "counts the number of times that each letter occurs in the specified string and returns the result as an int array, where the number of ‘A’s is stored at position [0], the number of ‘B’s is stored at position [1], and so on:".

Now I have tried to create the method wordInLetters but I am stuck as to how to proceed to create a method that does what the title of this post says.

```
static boolean wordInLetters(final String word, final int[] letterCounts) {
boolean hasEnough = true;
for (int i = 0; i <word.length(); i ++){
    if (word.charAt(i) < letterCounts[i]){
       hasEnough = false;
     
    }
    else {return true;}
}
return hasEnough;
}
```

}

Comment: Call the previously made function, passing the word as parameter. Then compare the values returned by it with the values in `letterCount` array. If they are all `<=` return `true`.

Comment: So I call letterCounts(word)? And then I do something like: if (letterCounts(word) <= int [] letterCounts){return true;}    ...?

Comment: how do I write the if statement? In other words, how do I compare those values?

Answer (score 0):

Call the previously made function, passing the word as parameter. Then compare the values returned by it with the values in `letterCount` array. If they are all `<=` return true.

Note: this assumes both arrays have the same length (i.e. `26` for ASCII alphabet).

```
static boolean wordInLetters(final String word, final int[] availableLetters)
{
    // Get the count of letters in the word
    int [] lettersInWord = letterCounts(word);
    // Compare the counts
    for (int i = 0; i < lettersInWord.length; i++) {
        // If not enough letters, fail
        if (availableLetters[i] < lettersInWord[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // If we made it to here, all is good.
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make a call to the other method. You can simply do this:

```
static boolean wordInLetters(final String word, final int[] letterCounts) {
    int start = 'a';
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i ++){
        final int x = i;
        Long count = Arrays.asList(word.split("")).stream()
                                                  .filter(w -> w.equals(word.substring(x, x + 1)))
                                                  .count();
        if (letterCounts[word.charAt(i) - start] < count) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: OP already has working code to count the letters. Why re-invent the wheel? Plus, your method, while impressive looking, seems excessive for the trivial task of counting letters when a simple loop would suffice. Lastly, given a string like "sssssss" and enough `s`s in `letterCounts`, your counting code gets called for each `s` which, again, is excessive.

Comment: We don't know what the metaphoric wheel looks like. It could ce square, hexagonal or round, so this code could be useful as an example of a different approach to the same result. A check for letters already counted could and should be implemented indeed.